# Seinfeld and Lovejoy Connection

Tags: reference, seinfeld, lovejoy

In the *Seinfeld* episode The Pitch (1992) George suggests a sitcom idea to Jerry wherein Jerry runs an antique store and "people come into the store and you get involved with their lives".

Now, this seems to have at least a passing similarity to the British tv show *Lovejoy* starring Ian McShane which began in 1986 and is based on a series of novels of the same name -- the first published in 1977.

Is there any connection here? Is there any evidence that the writers of Seinfeld were making a reference to a relatively obscure British comedy-drama series?

Comment: The show Lovejoy is far less about the store and far more about Lovejoy going on adventures in and around the local area to sniff out valuable antiques. Most of his sales are done via auction anyway.

Comment: For the record, George's description is literally the plot of *[Ghost Whisperer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_Whisperer)*